# Azure RDP download file only allows for password

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to Azure.  I created a VM, then clicked on the Connect button, selected RDP and downloaded the VM.rdp file.

When I open the rdp file, the username is set to "Keith McIntyre".  All I have is a password field.

Keith McIntyre is not the username I specified when I created the VM.

I have tried my Microsoft password and the password I specified for the VM admin account.  Neither work.

What is Azure expecting?

(I have deleted and recreated the VM, being very careful of username and password settings.)

I am attaching a png of the RDP connection window.

I have found nothing by searching the web and watching YouTube videos.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll use the Connect button in the Azure portal to start a Remote Desktop (RDP) session from a Windows desktop. First you connect to the virtual machine, and then you sign on.
This article explain how to [RDP to azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon)

[Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection)
The Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) connection to your Windows-based Azure virtual machine (VM) can fail for various reasons, leaving you unable to access your VM. The issue can be with the Remote Desktop service on the VM, the network connection, or the Remote Desktop client on your host computer. This article guides you through some of the most common methods to resolve RDP connection issues.

[Detailed troubleshooting steps for remote desktop connection issues to Windows VMs in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/detailed-troubleshoot-rdp)

If the issue still persist, after trying the above mentioned troubleshooting steps, please share the  screenshot of the issue.